# Juniper QFX Site to Site VPN

Tags: switch, vpn, juniper, ipsec, data-center

Im trying to setup a site to site vpn between two Juniper QFX5110's. Each end of the link is on the same subnet (so directly connected switches over dark fibre). I have configured each physical interface and can ping across the link.

When I try to setup the route based site to site vpn using this [doco](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/security-route-based-ipsec-vpns.html#id-example-configuring-a-route-based-vpn) as reference I have an issue when i get to the command

`set security ipsec vpn <name> ......`

ipsec vpn is not an option. I have ipsec proposal and ipsec policy but no vpn.

I'm pretty lost with this, I cant seem to find anything explaining why this commands is not there and how to make a secure tunnel without it.

Comment: If you don't have the same commands available on your devices than in the doc, then you probably run a different software. Are your devices up to date?

Comment: The doc you link to is for juniper SRX firewalls, I doubt IPSec is available on the QFX platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, QFX does not support [IPSec VPNs](https://apps.juniper.net/feature-explorer/parent-feature-info.html?pFKey=1401&pFName=Internet%20Protocol%20Security%20(IPsec)%20VPN), Teun Vink is right in that the documentation you posted is for the SRX as per the [requirements section.](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/security-route-based-ipsec-vpns.html#jd0e108)

Comment: Do you know if this switch supports MACSEC? I think from this it looks like it does. https://apps.juniper.net/feature-explorer/feature-info.html?fKey=8406&fn=Media%20Access%20Control%20Security%20(MACsec)

Comment: QFX5100 does, but the QFX5110 does not.